# When i check a checkbox and press update, i want my text to appear in textarea

Tags: jquery, html

i have created a simple generator for my personal uses and everything's going well except my checkbox,
I want it when i fill up everything and press generate also if the checkbox is checked it puts a tag to front and last example:

I couldn't find any solution for my issue since i couldn't explain it well so here i'm asking you guys

This is my demo:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/z4yuqk5e/>
```

I want it like: when i press "Generate" and if "Bold" is checked, i want it to generate the text with bold tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add simple condition: if `bold` is checked then wrap generated text with tag `b`. You can do it like this:

```
var toInsert = "<font color='" + $('#color').val() + " '>" + $('#choose_title').val() + "</font>";

if ($('#bold').is(':checked'))
    toInsert = "<b>" + toInsert + "</b>"

$('textarea').val(toInsert);
```

Full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mozkomor05/3c61k8fq/

> WARNING: Font tag is deprecated. Use span instead! (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358663/what-tag-should-i-use-instead-of-deprecated-tag-font-in-html-cannot-use-css))

Comment: I appreciate it, i know that but this generator is use for some game and span is not supported so i use Font tag